# param is missing or the value is empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, controller, nested-attributes

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in DuelersController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: dueler
```

How can I fix the error so that when a user clicks "Accept" or "Decline" it will change the value of `:accept`

```
Dueler.last
 id: 20,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 178,
 duel_id: 13,
 accept: nil>
```

**form**

```
<%= form_for @dueler do |f| %>
  <%= f.button "Accept", name: "button_action", value: "accept" %>
  <%= f.button "Decline", name: "button_action", value: "decline" %>
<% end %>
```

**duelers_controller.rb**

```
def update
  if params['button_action'] == 'accept'
    @dueler.accept = 1
  else
    @dueler.accept = 0
  end
  @dueler.update(dueler_params)
  redirect_to :back
end

def dueler_params
  params.require(:dueler).permit(:id, :duel_id, :user_id, :challenge_id, :accept)
end
```

**terminal**

```
Processing by DuelersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zn6Z9XuCQ2JahhtrZzFpEl3ENe+bcmOdDH/gz6VZ4p0mnRvgwpixdF2uA/sFgaQZFu2dEKR0DivQpJLqu96pxg==", "button_action"=>"accept", "id"=>"15"}
```

This is how the parameters look like when I submit with `:accept` as a `check_mark`, which doesn't raise any error:

```
Processing by DuelersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KWDac1I2rNRZd6oeCan0F7qlNY4c5K5vd6U988MJ6n3Bg1hm6yxewl5fso5rGTkc8YydcSPiw9mrfk/W3Y6hJg==", "dueler"=>{"accept"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Dueler", "id"=>"15"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix option 1:

`<%= form_for @dueler do |f| %>
  <%= f.button "Accept", name: "dueler[button_action]", value: "accept" %>
  <%= f.button "Decline", name: "dueler[button_action]", value: "decline" %>
<% end %>`

Quick fix option 2:

`def dueler_params
  params.permit(:id, :duel_id, :user_id, :challenge_id, :button_action)
end`

Option 3 - bigger changes, but I like it best

**form**

`<%= form_for @dueler do |f| %>
  <%= f.button "Accept", name: "dueler[accept]", value: 1 %>
  <%= f.button "Decline", name: "dueler[accept]", value: 0 %>
<% end %>`

**duelers_controller.rb**

`def update
  @dueler.update(dueler_params.merge(accept: dueler_params[:accept].to_i))
  redirect_to :back
end`

Either option should get you past this particular error. However, I worry that you're not fully understanding how pieces of your code work together. I expect the next part of your controller to behave differently than you'll expect:

`` if params['button_action'] == 'accept'
    @dueler.accept = 1
  else
    @dueler.accept = 0 # "accept" sounds like a Boolean piece of data to me, but it looks like you're saving it as an integer
  end
  @dueler.update(dueler_params) # I expect you'll get "undefined method `button_action=' for #<Dueler:0x007fc4fac732d0>" here ``

You may want to play with `form_for` and Strong Parameters a bit more to understand how arguments you pass to `button` and such turn into HTML, which then turn into params, and how they're handled in the controller.

Comment: `Option 3` worked perfectly :] Thanks for the additional explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Strong parameters seem to be dropping the "accept" value since it's not being associated with "dueler".  I might try putting a hidden check box in the view and then calling a function via an on-click listener that sets the check box to the appropriate value and then submits the form.

I wouldn't say it's the "right" way, but it may work for your case.